# SQL Server function error with if condition

Tags: sql-server

I'm still trying to learn an SQL, i made a mistakes but i already search on the internet about the if statements...
I tried to create a simple function to check if the parameter is match the condition..
I have 2 parameters, that will be inputted manually by the users, but i got an error saying

`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ufn_calculatebonus, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 1] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ufn_calculatebonus, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 1] A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.`

This is the code i've tried to create, i thought i make the IF condition right? After the IF , should have a BEGIN and statements, closing it with END. ??

```
CREATE FUNCTION Sales.ufn_calculatebonus (@CompanyRevenue int, @OptionalParameter varchar(60))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
IF @CompanyRevenue > 10
BEGIN
SELECT 'INPUT CANNOT BE BIGGER THAN 1000'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
RETURN
(
  SELECT * FROM SALES.CUSTBALANCE2 where region=@OptionalParameter or name=@OptionalParameter
);
END
GO
```

Comment: You cannot SELECT 'INPUT CANNOT BE BIGGER THAN 1000' consider another approach,

Comment: Since i wanted to return multiple rows, it should return as table right? So i should only change the SELECT 'INPUT CANNOT BE BIGGER THAN 1000' ? But i only wanted to give a warning to the users? So i needed to make a new table and insert data with the warning inside its field?

Comment: I suggest you peruse the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) and samples.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 distinct types of T-SQL table-valued functions, inline TVF and multi-statement TVF. The body of an inline TVF consists of only of a `RETURNS` statement with a query specification (not to be confused with a `RETURN` statement).

Your attempt at a multi-statement table-valued function is invalid for the reasons below.

1. The body of a multi-statement TVF must be surrounded with BEGIN...END.
2. A table variable with the returned schema must be declared in the function header.
3. One cannot return query results with a `RETURN` statement. Instead, insert results into the table variable declared in the function header end specify `RETURN` at the end of the function to return the results.

Below is an example of the remediated code. Importantly, note the use of an explicit column list throughout. Don't `SELECT *` in production code.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ufn_calculatebonus (@CompanyRevenue int, @OptionalParameter varchar(60))
RETURNS @BalanceInfo TABLE (CustomerID int, Balance int, ErrorMessage varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    IF @CompanyRevenue > 10
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @BalanceInfo (ErrorMessage) VALUES('INPUT CANNOT BE BIGGER THAN 1000');
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @BalanceInfo (CustomerID, Balance) --note ErrorMessage is omitted and will be NULL
            SELECT CustomerID, Balance FROM SALES.CUSTBALANCE2 where region=@OptionalParameter or name=@OptionalParameter;
    END;
    RETURN;
END
GO
```

A stored procedure is a better fit than a than user-defined function if you need to raise custom errors for parameter validation. Here's a stored procedure example:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_calculatebonus (@CompanyRevenue int, @OptionalParameter varchar(60))
AS
    IF @CompanyRevenue > 10
    BEGIN
        THROW 50000, 'INPUT CANNOT BE BIGGER THAN 1000', 16;
    END;
    SELECT CustomerID, Balance FROM SALES.CUSTBALANCE2 where region=@OptionalParameter or name=@OptionalParameter;
GO
```